# PTV Sequence Optimization: Restrict calculation to specific Country

Tags: ptv-developer

i have stops that are all close to French-German border, all stops are located in Germany though.
can i somehow specify that the calculation must take into consideration that the border can not be crossed?

i imagine something like in the Routing API where we can specify "options[allowedCountries]=DE"

Thx for your inputs!

so far, i went thru the doc, maybe i'm missing smthn